# Contextual actionbar at bottom

Tags: android, android-actionmode

In manifest.file under `<activity>` tag I have a declaration something like this:

`UIOptions :splitActionBarWhenNarrow`

When  I click on any checkbox from UI, then Contextual action bar is getting created . contextual actionbar items are getting loaded at top and white screen is showing at bottom action bar .

I want contextual action bar at bottom instead of white screen space. 
please help.

Comment: Under <activity> tag android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"